# How to insert value in SQL table if not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new in SQL. I'm trying to insert data into a SQL table. If I insert for the first time it works but if I try to do a new insert I get the error

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint.

The unique key constraint is on (uc, start_date). The error occurs because there is already the record (-1, 1900-01-01) in the table. Here is my code:

```
insert into tableA ([start_date],[end_date],[uc],[desc],[ind_sus])
select '1900-01-01' [start_date]  
       ,'9999-12-31'[end_date]
       ,case when right([DIM], 1) = '|' then '-1'
             else right([DIM], 2)
        end [uc] 
        ,'' [desc]
        ,0 [ind_sus]
from tableB b
     where right([DIM], 2) NOT IN (select uc from tableA a 
     where a.uc = right([DIM], 2)
     and convert(date,b.[DATETRIAL]) between a.start_date and a.end_date)
     group by case when right([DIM], 1) = '|' then '-1'
          else right([DIM], 2)
     end
```

The data that I'm trying to insert fulfills the when condition of the case and therefore another (-1, 1900-01-01) as key. I tried:

`case when not exists(select uc from tableA where uc = '-1') then '-1'`

to insert only if the data doesn't exist. It didn't work because I have to put the same code in the group by clause and I realized that I cannot do a subquery in the group by clause. So, is there a way to check at the case clause level if a value already exist before inserting? Or should I rewrite the request in another way? Database can't be modified
I need suggestions please.

Comment: create table again and remove unique key from column (uc,date)

Comment: @nafeesahmed..I can't modify the database

Comment: as nafees ahmed suggested, your column might be unique so that same value cannot occur again

Comment: If you're getting multiple duplicate values for (uc, start_date), how do you know which one you want to insert into the new table, since they could each have different values for the other columns?

Comment: @MikeFisher.the other columns have the same values. Only uc can change

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to check and insert data when not exists you need to use MERGE operator (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more info).

Since you did not provide us with test data, I'm not sure I can easily update your query, so here is an example I made up to show you how to do things you need using MERGE.

1. Create table and insert 1 row with id = 1:

   ```
    create table some_table(id int primary key, text_col varchar(10));
    insert into some_table values(1, 'first');
   ```
2. Try to insert a line with same id

   ```
    insert into some_table values(1, 'another first'); -- it fails of course
   ```
3. same thing using merge

   ```
    merge into some_table -- target table
    using 
      (select 1 id, 'another first' text_col) new_data -- source data
    on some_table.id = new_data.id -- column to check on
    when not matched then
      insert (id, text_col) values(new_data.id, new_data.text_col);
   ```

I hope this helps

My try to change your query to merge would be like that
(keep in mind I did not tested it so fixing syntax or possible data errors is up to you)

```
merge into tableA a 
using (select uc
              ,'1900-01-01' [start_date]  
              ,'9999-12-31'[end_date]
              ,case when right([DIM], 1) = '|' then '-1'
               else right([DIM], 2) end [uc] 
              ,'' [desc]
              ,0 [ind_sus]
         from tableB b
 group by case when right([DIM], 1) = '|' then '-1'
               else right([DIM], 2)
          end) b
 on a.right([DIM], 2) = b.uc 
   and convert(date,b.[DATETRIAL]) between a.start_date and a.end_date
 when not matched then
 insert([start_date],[end_date],[uc],[desc],[ind_sus]) 
 values(b.start_date, b.end_date, b.uc, b.desc, b.ind_sus)
```